# is there a python module that can fill native windows form fields?

Tags: python, windows, native

I want to know of any Python module that will help me enter form data within a native windows application IDE.

E.g. A password protected USB has an application to enter password. I want to automate this process by running the application and filling the form with the password.

Thanks in advance

roo7break

Answer (score 3):

The library [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) can be used for Windows GUI automation in Python.