# Moving data from excel to a DOS program

Tags: excel, batch-file, dos

I often have to input data from an excel spreadsheet into a DOS like program; this takes hours out of my day and it's done by printing out large amounts of paper and inputing them by hand.

Is there some function in excel that would allow this data to be transfered over to the DOS program? Basically it has to be entered one line at a time - an account number and then a quantity needs to be inputted, after that you press enter and do the next line of data (account & quantity).

Is there some kind of simple program that already exists that could do this? Thanks.

Comment: If the program you speak of has some sort of application programming interface, you may do it. What program is this? Do you mean you're just entering things using a graphical user interface?

Comment: Yeah it's an older GUI that our company has used since the 80's, currently the excel sheet is printer out and the data is entered into the GUI.

Comment: Is that _really_ a DOS program? There is no DOS available in current versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this solution using Python:
https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/

Found it through this SO thread:
[is there a python module that can fill native windows form fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364779/is-there-a-python-module-that-can-fill-native-windows-form-fields)

A possible workflow may be:

1. Use excel to save your excel file as a .CSV file
2. Use the [Python CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read .CSV data into a Python program
3. Use the solution mentioned above to enter that data into your GUI program.

Even if you do not know Python, I suggest you give it a stab. There is not a lot of overhead in learning it, and you'll have huge return on investments.

Comment: This was pretty much what we ended up doing. Cheers!